# auto select current tab for getusermedia in headless chrome

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, headless, getusermedia

I am trying to record a webpage in nodejs server.
Currently I am using puppeteer to open a page and a extension to record it.
I want to ditch the extension and directly record in the nodejs.

So first problem is to get the stream from current tab. This can be done in extension but in the browser itself it requires a user confirmation.

So I was wondering is there any chrome config or commandline params that would disable the user confirmation popup when using `getusermedia` and automatically returns the current tab ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no Chrome configuration or command-line parameter that directly bypasses the user confirmation for `getUserMedia` to capture the current tab automatically due to privacy and security concerns. 

To record a webpage in Node.js without relying on user interaction or an extension, you may explore using Puppeteer to simulate user actions or capture screenshots and piece together a video, though it requires a different approach from direct stream recording.

Comment: screenshots won't work because I need audio too @jC61